# Выход за стену Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

В программке бегает текстура туда-сюда рандомно, а если стукается о стены - меняет направление движения. Всё бы хорошо, но текстуркой управляют два метода, один за отражение от стен, другой за хаотичное движение. Когда они совпадают, а текстура близко к стене - она может пройти сквозь стену.

Можно как нибудь сделать так чтобы **оно не при каких обстоятельствах** не могло пройти через стену? Стены разумеется с Box Collider 2d и Rigidbody 2d

Почему не при каких обстоятельствах - потому что эта проблема была еще до элемента рандома. Просто иногда, оставишь текстуру бегать по полю, а она через полчаса пролетит сковозь стену как ни в чем не бывало. А с рандомом постоянно такое стало.

код

```
 {
Vector2 dir;
Transform myTransform;
public float angle;
public float vx = 1f;
public float vy = 1f;
public float speed = 1f;


void Start()
{

    InvokeRepeating("Running", 2, 3);

    myTransform = transform;

    dir = Vector2.up;

    myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);


}
void Running()
{

    var random = Random.Range(-10, 10);
    var random1 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
    var random3 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
    vy = random1;
    vx = random;


    angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, new Vector2(vy, vx));
    if (random3 > 0)

    { angle = -angle; }

    dir = Vector2.up;

    myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
}


void Update()
{
    myTransform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);

}




void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{




        if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bbot"))
        {

            myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle - Random.Range(-80, 80));
        }
        if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bleft"))
        {

            myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle + Random.Range(185, 350));
        }
        if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("bright"))
        {

            myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle - Random.Range(185, 350));
        }
        if (coll.gameObject.name.StartsWith("btop"))
        {

            myTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle - Random.Range(100, 260));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо того чтобы двигать самостоятельно тело, отдайте это во власть физики на Unity. Рассчитывайте случайную силу и вместо `transform.Translate()` делайте `rigidbody2D.AddForce()` тогда у вас объект будет двигаться по законам физики а не телепортироваться на каждом кадре. Силу прикладывать надо в методе `FixedUpdate` где обсчитывается физика на каждом шаге, а не в `Update` который выполняется перед сменой кадра. Да и если у вас физика работает и мелкий объект проскакивает через другой объект, то попробуйте поменять в объекте `Rigidbody2D` параметры `Interpolate` и `Collision Detection`, обычно помогает.)

Comment: Спасибо! rigidbody2d.AddForce() работает полностью с теми же командами как и transform.Translate? Какие нюансы? Никогда просто с ним ранее не работал.

Comment: Нет принцип другой. В `transform` вы меняете положение объекта в пространстве, а в `rigidbody` задаете направление и силу которая воздействует на объект. Изменять положение в пространстве будет уже движок с физикой. Если на текстурке будет свой колайдер с `rigidbody` то в общем то и обсчитывать столкновение текстурки не придется, за вас это все движок сделает.

Comment: что то не обсчитывает. Сделал так    

`{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        rb.AddForce( new Vector2(0, 10));

    }
}`

Тело набирает скорость и абсолютно спокойно проходит сквозь стены. Что добавить в код чтобы оно просто упиралось в стену, раз это 2 физических тела с массой?

Comment: Стена имеет `collider` и `rirgidbody`? Вы меняли у оъекта `Rigidbody2D` параметры `Interpolate` и `Collision Detection`?

Comment: Да, все пробовал. Толку мало, всё равно иногда вылетает. Перенес в 3D и забил, там стены крепче)